# python/beautifulsoup: find previous row with particular attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm scraping an html file with a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr valign="bottom"><td colspan="3"><p> <br/><b>PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae</b></p></td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Summer Tanager</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=891798D9EFFE1F8D"><i>Piranga rubra</i></a></td><td>Piranga vermillon</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Scarlet Tanager</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=4210163221C2E458"><i>Piranga olivacea</i></a></td><td>Piranga écarlate</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Rose-breasted Grosbeak</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=7C2FCB13BAA660EE"><i>Pheucticus ludovicianus</i></a></td><td>Cardinal à poitrine rose</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr valign="bottom"><td colspan="3"><p> <br/><b>PASSERIFORMES: Buntings</b></p></td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Indigo Bunting</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=043F337AA25E7D97"><i>Passerina cyanea</i></a></td><td>Passerin indigo</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Dickcissel</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=592E58CE67D092DA"><i>Spiza americana</i></a></td><td>Dickcissel d'Amérique</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm having no problem getting the values of the "tr class="highlight1" rows and popping them into a csv by doing this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r"/Users/user/Downloads/birds.html"), 'lxml')
english = [item.text for item in soup.select('tr[class] td:nth-of-type(1)')]
latin = [item.text for item in soup.select('tr[class] td:nth-of-type(2)')]
french = [item.text for item in soup.select('tr[class] td:nth-of-type(3)')]
status = [item.text for item in soup.select('tr[class] td:nth-of-type(4)')]
link = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('tr[class] a[href]')]

test = zip(english,latin,french,status,link)
with open('birdfile.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    csv_out = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_out.writerows(test)
```

What I would like to do is grab the value in "tr valign="bottom"" for each row. Basically, I know how to go forward and drill down using the css selector in beautifulsoup, but I can't figure out how to go backwards and select **the "tr valign="bottom"" just prior to each "tr class="highlight1""**.

I want my csv output to look like this:

```
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae,Summer Tanager,Piranga rubra...
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae,Scarlet Tanager,Piranga olivacea...
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae,Rose-breasted Grosbeak,Pheucticus ludovicianus...
PASSERIFORMES: Buntings,Indigo Bunting,Passerina cyanea...
PASSERIFORMES: Buntings,Dickcissel,Spiza americana...
```

I can't find any examples quite like this and I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want solution without `pandas`, you can use this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<table>
<tr valign="bottom"><td colspan="3"><p> <br/><b>PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae</b></p></td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Summer Tanager</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=891798D9EFFE1F8D"><i>Piranga rubra</i></a></td><td>Piranga vermillon</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Scarlet Tanager</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=4210163221C2E458"><i>Piranga olivacea</i></a></td><td>Piranga écarlate</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Rose-breasted Grosbeak</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=7C2FCB13BAA660EE"><i>Pheucticus ludovicianus</i></a></td><td>Cardinal à poitrine rose</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr valign="bottom"><td colspan="3"><p> <br/><b>PASSERIFORMES: Buntings</b></p></td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Indigo Bunting</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=043F337AA25E7D97"><i>Passerina cyanea</i></a></td><td>Passerin indigo</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
<tr class="highlight1"><td>Dickcissel</td><td><a href="species.jsp?avibaseid=592E58CE67D092DA"><i>Spiza americana</i></a></td><td>Dickcissel d'Amérique</td><td>Rare/Accidental </td></tr>
</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select('tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))'):
    all_data.append([
        tr.find_previous('td', {'colspan': True}).get_text(strip=True), 
        *[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')] 
    ])

# print data to screen:
for row in all_data:
    print(*row, sep=', ')
```

Prints:

```
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae, Summer Tanager, Piranga rubra, Piranga vermillon, Rare/Accidental
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae, Scarlet Tanager, Piranga olivacea, Piranga écarlate, Rare/Accidental
PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae, Rose-breasted Grosbeak, Pheucticus ludovicianus, Cardinal à poitrine rose, Rare/Accidental
PASSERIFORMES: Buntings, Indigo Bunting, Passerina cyanea, Passerin indigo, Rare/Accidental
PASSERIFORMES: Buntings, Dickcissel, Spiza americana, Dickcissel d'Amérique, Rare/Accidental
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Ugh, I completely missed that BeautifulSoup has a find_previous function! This does answer my question for a solution without using pandas (though I'm still curious about how that might work!).

Answer (score 3):

You could simply read your table into pandas and then slice and dice it however you see fit:

```
import pandas as pd
langs = """your html above"""
df=pd.read_html(langs)
df[0]
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
    0                               1                               2                      3
0   PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae     PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae     PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae     NaN
1   Summer Tanager                  Piranga rubra                   Piranga vermillon   Rare/Accidental
2   Scarlet Tanager                 Piranga olivacea                Piranga écarlate    Rare/Accidental
3   Rose-breasted Grosbeak          Pheucticus ludovicianus         Cardinal à poitrine rose    Rare/Accidental
4   PASSERIFORMES: Buntings         PASSERIFORMES: Buntings         PASSERIFORMES: Buntings     NaN
5   Indigo Bunting                  Passerina cyanea                Passerin indigo     Rare/Accidental
6   Dickcissel                      Spiza americana                 Dickcissel d'Amérique   Rare/Accidental
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still unsure how to change that output into rows that look like this: 
1 PASSERIFORMES: Cardinalidae                 Summer Tanager                  Piranga rubra                   Piranga vermillon